# Adding a line independent of y to the axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a table with some column, let's say: years 1910-1935, number of sold product, and some arithmetic mean in the last col.

I try to plot it in ggplot in R. And I got a proper plot for year~mean. But my problem is: 
I need to add a line to that plot with years~sold products. They have a completely different value (the first plot have a Y value: 0 - 3.5, second: 0 - 1400). So if I try to add my second line, the first values are flatting.

How can I include the second chart so that the years are based on the X axis (i.e. years from the first chart) and sold products get a new Y2 axis on the right (so that they do not flatten the chart)?

I tried to add new plot to another, but the Y2 didn't fit to first plot area (i had a Y2 axis inside a plot area).

Code:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,5,5))
ggplot(prod, aes(year, mean)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "red")

#ggplot(prod, aes(year, numOfProd)) + geom_line() 
ggplot(prod, aes(year, mean)) + geom_smooth(method="glm", formula=y~poly(x,3), se=FALSE, colour ="red") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula=y~x, se = FALSE, colour = "blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", colour = "blue") +
  #geom_point() +
  xlab("year of sold") + ylab("Mean[%]") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(inbred_wszystko$rur), max(prod$year), by = 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(prod$mean), max(prod$mean), by = 0.2))

par(new=TRUE)


## Plot the second plot and put axis scale on right

    par(mar=c(5,5,5,5))
    plot(prod$year, all_prod$numOfprod, xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0,1500), 
         axes=FALSE, type="l", col="dark green")
    mtext("Example",side=4,col="black",line=4) 
    axis(4, ylim=c(0,1500), col="black",col.axis="black",las=2)
```

So resume:
I need to add a line from the second plot (after the second comment) to first plot. They based on the same X.axis but values on Y are different. And also I need to add Y2 axis for that line on right side of the plot. Can someone help?

EDIT:
Sample data:

```
year    mean    soldProd
1910    0.5 798
1911    0.6 4234
1912    0.3 25
1913    0.1 2423
1914    0.6 4242
1915    0.3 5
1916    0.1 21
1917    0.11    442
1918    0.5 2353
1919    0.6 23
1920    0.3 42
1921    0.1 34
1922    0.3 235
1923    0.1 2
1924    0.5 5
1925    0.5 23
1926    0.5 235
1927    0.6 23
1928    0.3 4
1929    0.1 234
1930    0.5 2
1931    0.5 5
1932    0.5 2
1933    0.6 6
1934    0.3 4
1935    0.1 36
```

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this thread for ideas. It sounds similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Comment: Could you provide some sample data using `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: Could you post the output of `dput(data)`, please? This can be read into a variable so that I do not have to type your data. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot`'s `sec.axis` option.

Here is an example using some sample data that should be somewhat comparable to yours.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


prod <- data.frame(year=1910:1935, mean=sample(seq(0.1, 0.6, 0.1), 26, replace = T), soldProd=sample(4:2000, 26))

gg <- ggplot(prod, aes(year, mean)) + geom_smooth(method="glm", formula=y~poly(x,3), se=FALSE, colour ="red") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula=y~x, se = FALSE, colour = "blue") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", colour = "blue") +
  #geom_point() +
  xlab("year of sold") + ylab("Mean[%]") 

gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
y.range <- gb$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
y2.range <- extendrange(range(prod$soldProd), f=0.01)
prod$scaledSoldProd <- rescale(prod$soldProd, y.range, y2.range)
scale_factor <- (diff(y.range)/max(y2.range))
trans <- ~ ((. -y.range[1])/scale_factor)

gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=scaledSoldProd))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(prod$mean), max(prod$mean), by = 0.2),
                              sec.axis = sec_axis(trans, name = "Number of products"))

print(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it works almost perfectly. Can you tell me how to make this black line a bit smoother like a red one? I tried with geome_smooth but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: You could use `geom_smooth()` instead of `geom_line()` for `scaledSoldProd` and play around with the number of polynomials. This will, however, not match the original points exactly...